# JQuery: Access Dynamic Element after append

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with accessing the Elements that appended in my [website](http://www.goftare.com).
this is my code:

```
socket.on('userupdate', function (data) {
    var userslist = [];
    $('#users-list').html('');
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        userslist.push("<a><li id='chat-private' username=" + item.username + " userid=" + item.userid + ">" + item.username + "</li></a>");
    });
    $('#users-list').append(userslist);
});
$("#chat-private").click(function () {
    alert("We have Access!");
});
```

but nothing happened. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you want the give the `chat-private` elements a class, otherwise you will have duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid.

Secondly, you need to use a delegated event handler because those elements are not present in the DOM on page load. Try this:

```
socket.on('userupdate', function (data) {
    var userslist = [];
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        userslist.push("<li class='chat-private' username=" + item.username + " userid=" + item.userid + "><a>" + item.username + "</a></li>");
    });
    $('#users-list').html('').append(userslist);
});
$('#users-list').on('click', '.chat-private', function () {
    alert("We have Access!");
});
```

Note also that the `a` element should be inside the `li`, otherwise the HTML will be invalid and you may get rendering errors.

Answer (score 2):

As you are creating elements dynamically, You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

As IDs must be unique, You should use class selector

```
//Add class
userslist.push("<li class='chat-private' username=" + item.username + " userid=" + item.userid + "><a>" + item.username + "</a></li>");

//Bind event
$('#users-list').on('click', '.chat-private', function(){
    //Your code
    alert("We have Access!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you first append the click handler to #chat-private (wich not exists) and then make the div. You can do 2 things to solve your problem:

1. Append the click handler when you make the div
2. Use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to attatch a handler to all (inc. future) elements